# What is the purpose of a primary key class (xxxPK.java) in Hibernate/Java and when is it appropriate to define one?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am not familiar with Hibernate. I am trying to understand the purpose of defining a primary key class in Hibernate and where it would be appropriate.

I have to add new classes to some old code (early versions of Hibernate). I have a table called LOG which has the following fields *among other fields*

```
ID NUMBER
TRANS_ID VARCHAR2(40)
```

ID is the primary key (populated by oracle sequence). TRANS_ID is unique and populated by the application. Only search needed is by the TRANS_ID. *There are no composite keys.*

I believe I will need to define an entity class called Log.java and DAO class called LogDAO.java but do I need to define a LogPK.java for the Id field?  I would not like to define one if this is not needed in my situation.

Comment: You would use a primary key class if your primary key consists of several columns that cannot be otherwise handled in JPA or Hibernate.

Comment: This can be generalized by saying: you need a primary key class if you need a primary key of a class not being a native Java class directly mapped by the ORM to a SQL one. And most of the time, it's because it's a compound key.